# Middleware on route and in controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am attempting to run middleware on specific routes as well as inside controller constructor.

However, it appears middleware that are defined inside the controller constructor are not being executed for the routes that include middleware.

Is this not possible? (all of these middleware are registered in kernel.php, all middleware in constructor working before adding middleware to route)

**Route**

```
Route::get('/{organization_slug}', function($organization_slug){

    $organization = \App\Organization::where('slug', '=', $organization_slug)->first();

    $app = app();
    $controller = $app->make('\App\Http\Controllers\OrganizationController');
    return $controller->callAction('details', $parameters = array($organization->id));

})->middleware('verifyorganizationslug');
```

**Controller Constructor**

```
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth', ['only' => ['create', 'update', 'store']]);
        $this->middleware('accountactive', ['only' => ['create', 'update', 'store']]);
        $this->middleware('ownsorganization', ['only' => ['update']]);
        $this->middleware('verifyorganization', ['only' => ['details']]);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In [`gatherMiddleware`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php#L748), unique middleware are selected after merging route middleware with controller middleware.

```
public function gatherMiddleware()
{
    if (! is_null($this->computedMiddleware)) {
        return $this->computedMiddleware;
    }
    $this->computedMiddleware = [];
    return $this->computedMiddleware = array_unique(array_merge(
        $this->middleware(), $this->controllerMiddleware()
    ), SORT_REGULAR);
}
```

If you're viewing action mapped to `details` method, you should see `verifyorganizationslug` then `verifyorganization` applied.

Depending on which route you're viewing, the `computedMiddleware` will always have `verifyorganizationslug` middleware applied and other middleware specified for that route in the controller applied.

[Route controller `getMiddleware` filters all middleware not belonging in that method](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php#L64).

```
public function getMiddleware($controller, $method)
{
    if (! method_exists($controller, 'getMiddleware')) {
        return [];
    }
    return collect($controller->getMiddleware())->reject(function ($data) use ($method) {
        return static::methodExcludedByOptions($method, $data['options']);
    })->pluck('middleware')->all();
}
```

#### IMPORTANT

Now, your code runs around the request-response `Pipeline` which ensures that middleware are applied in order explained above. You lose the application of controller middleware as [`isControllerAction` returns false](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php#L791) because it's a `Closure` and not a `string`.

Fast forward, you want to use:

```
Route::get('/{organization_slug}', '\App\Http\Controllers\FooController@details')
     ->middleware('foo');
```

Then resolve `organization_slug` inside of your controller.

```
public function details(Request $request, $organisation_slug)
{
   $organization = \App\Organization::where('slug', '=', $organization_slug)
                       ->first();
   ...
}
```

Or consider using [*Route binding*](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#explicit-binding) to bind `organization_slug` route parameter to an instance of the organization.✌️

Comment: The last line in my controller constructor is applying middleware `verifyorganization` (different from the middleware `verifyorganizationslug` being applied in the route file) to the `details` function. This is not executing when details method invoked in my route as displayed.